# Add where clause to setParameter JPA

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jpa

At the moment I only know that you can do this in JPA

```sql
SELECT art_bezeichnung FROM table WHERE art_nr = :parameter
```

```java
.setParameter("parameter", "H03")
```

But can you also add a whole where clause via a parameter

```sql
SELECT art_bezeichnung FROM table :parameter
```

```java
.setParameter("parameter", "WHERE art_nr = H03")
```

I searched the Internet for it, but couldn´t find a clear answer.

Comment: Do you try to build a query with a dynamic number of parameters?

Comment: Yeah, because for example if an end date is given I need a `where year(date) < :enddate` otherwise i dont need this where.

Comment: Then, follow the answer from Phillip Schneider. The "WHERE" is needed just once, the predicates are usually combined with an `AND`.

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible because of possible SQL-Injection.

Use a if statement instead:

if (Parameter is set) add where to SQL Statement and Parameter.

Comment: Is there anything else that I can use instead of if statements, because if you have more then 5 different cases it could be that the code is difficult to read.

Comment: No. You can use some patterns to make it readable. Like decorator pattern or some other.